# Assign address address in UDP connection between two directly connected computers

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to exchange messages between client and server which are on two different machines. The two machines are directly connected by an Ethernet cable. I can successfully send and receive messages between client and server if they are both on the same machine. What should be the server address in order to have communication between the two machines?

```
serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( ???? );
```

I've tried running `ifconfig` on the server machine but just found the MAC address and no IP to assign in the code.

Both machines are running DHCP.

Comment: Yeah.. with just a twisty cable, and no DHCP server, you will have to manually set static IP addresses, eg 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2.

Comment: TBH, with modern NICs, you may not even need a twisted cable since they may auto-configure.  Not sure..

Comment: @user3386109, `command not found?`

Comment: What kind of OS are implemented on the server & client?

Comment: Both machines run Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [the UDP wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), as you can see, it requires an network layer. This is typically IP. You can set a static IP address to both devices and use these static IP address or you can set up a DHCP server on one of these machines to assign IP addresses automatically.

Comment: What is an "internet layer"? There is no such thing.

Comment: sorry, network layer i mean, i used the naming used on Wikipedia to prevent confusing with the link i provided.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenArits for your answer. I'll go again through the wiki. I've updated my question saying that I've DHCP on both machines.

Comment: Are they running the DHCP server on that specific connection or on another port?

Comment: Yes, on that specific connection.

Comment: I would have a look at your configuration of one of these DHCP servers, you need to set address ranges, a mask and maybe the IP address op te DHCP server itself.

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/22835/how-to-network-two-ubuntu-computers-using-ethernet-without-a-router

Answer (score 1):

Directly connecting the machines with a cable creates a unique independent network (with only the two nodes).

Note that the cable will have to be a crossover cable.

DHCP probably won't help if neither node is a DHCP server.

As indicated in the answer by Marrten Arias, assign both the client, and the server a static ip address; perhaps something like this:

```
Server IP: 192.168.01.01
Client IP: 192.168.01.02
Mask (for both): 255.255.255.0
```